# AccuRev - promoting quicker projects past larger ones

Tags: accurev

I feel like I'm experiencing a common problem, but I wasn't able to find anyone asking about it.

As the title indicates, we're forced to use AccuRev for SCM. We have our development stream under our QA stream. Let's say we're working on a big project that will be in QA for weeks before being released (we're following a scrum strategy). In the meantime, there's a bug fix that needs to go out before this big project. The problem is the bug fix affects some of the same files the big project uses. How would I get my files from development to production, without bringing the big project with me?

Sorry, I hope that makes sense!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution that will work for us.

I plan on creating a snapshot off of the development stream after each successful deployment to production. Bug fixes/smaller projects will work off of this snapshot. That way I can keep anything I'm currently working on in DEV from getting inherited into my bug fix. When I'm ready to deploy my bug fix, I'll create another snapshot and re-parent my big project there. Then I'll revert the change package in QA and development, re-parent my bug fix to development, and promote as normal.
It's a slightly modified version of what's explained in this article: https://accurev.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/pattern-for-stable-development/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the change package feature in AccuRev, you can select that issue and just promote those changes into the production stream.

Otherwise, you will need to determine the promote transaction(s) of the of the bug you fixed in development and change palette those fixes into production.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please forgive my ignorance, but I'm not sure I follow. Let's imagine that the bug fix is in index.html, but there's a bigger project in QA that's already made changes to index.html. When I send index.html to the issue for the bug fix, it would have the changes for the bigger project too. But I wouldn't want those changes to go out with the bug fix. How would I resolve this?

Comment: You are not going to change pallette the file index.html as that will include the changes in QA.  You want to patch over just the bug fix changes.

Comment: Are you using change packages?    If so, when you promoted index.html and associated the change to the bug fix issue.   If you are not using change packages, you wont have this association.   In the case you have change packages turned on, you will select the bug fix issue and change palette into production.

Comment: Otherwise, you will need to open a workspace off the production stream open the browse version gui for index.html select the promote version that contains the bug fix, right click -> patch from.  Once you have patched in the changes, promote into production.

Comment: Change packages are the same as issues, right? If so, yes, we are using change packages.
I think my main problem is how do I remove the things that won't go out with my bug fix from the development stream? I need to be able to test my bug fix in our development environment which gets built and deployed from our development stream in AccuRev.
I know I can "Show History" and revert a promote, but I could have many promotes to revert to get back to the version I need. It seems like there should be an easier way. Is there a way to revert a stream back to a certain point in time?

Comment: Yes, change packages are issues.

Comment: Create a new stream off of your development stream called development_staging.  You will change palette the bug fix issue into this stream.  In doing so, you will end up patching in just the changes for the bug fix though a merge algorithm.  You will do this in a workspace off the development_staging stream.  Once the patch/merge is complete, you will promote those changes into the development_staging stream.  At this point, you can build/test the stream.  Once you are happy, promote into development stream.

Comment: If you need to revert your changes from a stream, you can revert the issue you promoted from the stream.

Comment: I really appreciate your patience in answering my questions, but I don't think this will work in our case. In reality, it could be multiple files that need to be patched in, and those files could have external dependencies that would require others to be reverted back. Also, the same needs to be done in the QA stream for our QA team. QA would be above the parent development stream.

Comment: While I appreciate all your help and have upvoted your answer, I might have found a solution that will work for us involving Snapshots. If it works out, I'll add it as an answer later.
By the way, I just saw your last comment. In keeping with the agile methodology, the issue could be promoted to the development and QA stream multiple times.